High or tall car and desk and screen?
With which adjective is it natural to use the words screen, car/vehicle, table.
I already know that when something is high off the ground, it has great distance between itself and the ground. Tall is used for people or things which are higher than they are wide, e.g. a tower. High is used when something is wider then it is high. This is general guide to  correct use but native speakers are just all over place in this regard or seem to be so.

The vehicle is too high/tall. Getting in it isn't super easy because you kind of have to climb.

Take the kid off the table! The table is high/tall and he could get injured if he falls off it.

Thanks to the wide and high/tall screen of the TV, you can enjoy your TV without having to sit close to the screen.

A bus is usually twelve feet tall/high. (Might not be factual)

Her desk at work is too high/tall for her.

The table is 3 feet tall/high.



Does this answer your question? "high" vs. "tall". Also How tall/high is the Empire State building? and "The building is tall" Vs. "The building is high" and "high building" vs. "tall building", among others.

Vehicles and furniture are high, not tall. TV screens have a fixed ratio between their height and width, so we usually just say they are big, not 'wide and high'.

@KateBunting: I don't think that's completely accurate. There are far more tall buses in Google Books today than there are high buses.

@FumbleFingers - OK, I grant you that a double-decker bus can be tall.

A high vehicle will often refer to the riding/driving position or the ground clearance, rather than the distance from ground to top of the roof. Although it varies with vehicle type: a high truck is more likely to refer to one with a cargo space that goes up in the air a long way.

@KateBunting "Vehicles and furniture are high, not tall"—Really? While I can think of things like "highchair" or "high-backed settle," I would see these as outliers normally use "tall" for these categories (a tall truck, a tall dresser).

Actually, I retract my close vote since this isn't a good duplicate and will contribute an answer. Spoiler alert, no, it's not consistent.

@AndyBonner - OK - I was thinking of a high (or low) table, a child's high chair and the like. I agree that I was too quick to generalise.

Hello user635, I saw this question in the close queue and immediately made the connection to the question you posted earlier today and have now deleted https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/353657/high-or-tall-in-these-contexts-whats-the-difference. It's in your own best interests not to ask the same question repeatedly. I know understand why your newer question was downvoted, because I didn't think it was that bad. Arguably if you had mentioned that you asked the same question just four days ago, it would have been closed as duplicate.

You complained Why do you guys even bother to write in the first place if you don't want to answer? My comments were meant for you to reflect on. You sound like a kid, maybe 18-20 years old, you need to chill and not get all defensive. You can improve this post, and probably get better answers if you put in a little extra effort and edit your question and EXPLAIN why the two answers do not help you.

You need to explain why the questions listed by FumbleFingers are not helpful otherwise this question is likely to get closed as a duplicate. Don't just throw in the towel and post an identical question with a different account and think we all are stupid because no one can be bothered to post an answer. It's not true, people do post answers and people see and remember two questions that are identical to each other [end of lecture].

Here's the simplest abstraction: "high" is where you are, while "tall" is what you are. "High" speaks of location while "tall" speaks of a measurable dimension.
Now, that is a huge oversimplification. There are many exceptions and contradictions, and allowable overlap. And it gets confusing immediately because the noun form of that measurable dimension is "height." "Height" isn't a measurement of how "high" you are; that's altitude. Rather, "height" is how "tall" you are. Much more confusing than "wide" and "width"!
There are also many uses that seem contradictory. We might speak of "a high desk" or "a tall desk." That would be because we're focusing on a part of the desk, the desktop. Both words would be equally acceptable in this example. Similarly, we use a "high chair" to feed babies at a convenient height. This piece of furniture, with its long legs, is tall, but presumably we use "high" because the sitting surface and the baby are lifted up high.
I can also think of other uses that would seem to go against this rule of thumb, like a "high-backed settee" or antiquated references like "a high tower," when meaning a tower that is very tall, not merely positioned on elevated ground. This might be because we got into all this trouble in the first place as language evolved; from Etymology Online it looks like the Old English root held both meanings.
There are many situations in which uses that go against my rule of thumb are just fine. Many of the similar questions linked in the comments show that using "high" to describe a very large object might be totally reasonable, like a "high mountain" or "high building." In general, though, there is more room to use "high" to describe a tall thing than vice versa. When a young child climbs a tree and says "Look, Daddy! I'm tall!," we laugh, because they are jokingly speaking of their temporary positioning as if it were an inherent attribute. This ngram shows that it's much more common to speak of a "high shelf" than a "tall shelf," but that using "tall shelf" does happen, and is increasing.

I don't think "location" is an apt abstraction for height or altitude.  And to cast the choice as "acceptable/inacceptable" is to overlook that the whole point of language is to express an idea as clearly as you can, not as acceptably as you can.

@TimR Well, I mean, the OP's goal is presumably to find usages that don't "sound odd." Many usages might be counter to trends but don't stand out noticeably; those that do "sound odd" is what I was thinking of as "unacceptable." (IMO we've evolved into many patterns that are not clear, especially to learners, but are idiomatic!) But meanwhile, could you explain more about "location"?

high is an expression of the altitude of something relative to a base, whereas tall expresses an intrinsic absolute dimension.  And so depending on what you're referring to with, say, the vehicle, you could use either.
If the vehicle is too high, perhaps it's difficult to get in because you have to step up. If it's too tall, maybe it cannot fit under a bridge with low clearance.
So you have to ask yourself whether you're referring to a relative altitude or an absolute dimension.
If I say "My monitor is too high", I am referring to its relative position for me when I'm at my desk. If I say it's too tall, I'm talking about its instrinsic dimension; maybe I must look up to see text at the top, even when the monitor is at its lowest height setting, and  I get a crick in my neck from looking at URLs  in the browser's address bar all day.

It's still not clear. Can you please answer in relation to my sentences?

@K945 I'm not going to do your homework for you.

I am not even in school anymore but never mind. I just want to understand the difference.

This is not the first time where, after a number of people have explained things to you, you have said something to the effect of "I don't get it. Please stick to my examples".  I've explained an essential difference between the two that should help you decide which one to use.

@K945 I would boil this down as "high is where you are, tall is what you are." With the warning that it's a rule of thumb and there are exceptions.
